# How to test a Singleton class?

Tags: ruby, singleton, rspec, testing

I am using RSpec and want to test the constructor of a Singleton class more than one time.

How can I do this?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at http://blog.ardes.com/2006/12/11/testing-singletons-with-ruby:

```
require 'singleton'

class <<Singleton
  def included_with_reset(klass)
    included_without_reset(klass)
    class <<klass
      def reset_instance
        Singleton.send :__init__, self
        self
      end
    end
  end
  alias_method :included_without_reset, :included
  alias_method :included, :included_with_reset
end
```

Comment: The problem with this is, global state is modified when your tests run. See my answer below for a cleaner way.

Answer (score 28):

Singleton classes essentially do this

```
def self.instance
  @instance ||= new
end

private_class_method :new
```

So you can bypass the memoization altogether by calling the private method new using send

```
let(:instance) { GlobalClass.send(:new) }
```

A nice benefit of this way is that no global state is modified as a result of your tests running.

---

Probably a better way, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26172556/633234):

```
let(:instance) { Class.new(GlobalClass).instance }
```

This creates an anonymous class which inherits from `GlobalClass`, which all class-level instance variables are stored in. This is then thrown away after each test, leaving `GlobalClass` untouched.

Comment: This is a simple, direct solution.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks! this should be the correct answer

Comment: `Class.new` is ok if there is no run-time dependency on the class name (because the new anonymous class wouldn't have that name).  If there is a name dependency (e.g. the Observer name in the observer gem), using `.send(:new)` instead should work.

Answer (score 8):

```
# singleton_spec.rb
require "singleton"

class Global
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    puts "Initializing"
  end
end

describe Global do
  before do
    Singleton.__init__(Global)
  end

  it "test1" do
    Global.instance
  end

  it "test2" do
    Global.instance
  end
end


% rspec singleton_spec.rb -fd
Global
Initializing
  test1
Initializing
  test2
```

Comment: The key is "Singleton.__init__(Global)". That nailed it for me. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is, this resets the singleton. If any other parts of your app rely on global state that was set earlier, this will break. For example, if you're using the registry pattern, then how do you test the registry without breaking the tests for components that use the registry?

Answer (score 3):

One pattern I've seen is having the singleton be a sub-class of the real class.  You use the Singleton version in production code, but the base (non-singleton) class for testing.

Example:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :some_state

  def initialize
     @some_state = {}
  end
end

class MySingletonClass < MyClass
  include Singleton
end
```

...but I'm looking for a better way myself.

Part of my problem is that I'm using JRuby and hooking into the Java System Preferences, which *are* global.  The rest I think I can refactor out.

Answer (score 2):

One reason people use singletons because "global variables are bad, m'kay?"  A singleton is a global variable, sequestered in a name space, and with lazy instantiation.  Consider whether a true global variable might simplify things, especially if you don't need lazy instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor it into a class that can be constructed multiple times. This has the side-effect (some would say benefit) of removing the Singleton nature from the class.

Look at it another way: you've found a need to call the constructor more than once. Why *should* the class only construct one instance? What benefit is Singleton providing?

Comment: The constructor does not need to get called more than once but I want to keep my specs clear - so I am testing only one part of the constructor in each spec.

Answer (score 0):

Does RSpec allow you do perform pre-test actions? Is so, you could add another method to you static class that cleared anything done during the constructor. Then just call that prior to each and every test.

Comment: RSpec has "before" and "after" blocks. http://rspec.info/documentation/before_and_after.html

Comment: But the constructor won't get called twice because of the Singleton Pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply make a new `it` and block for each spec. Break down your spec to a testable unit. Use "before" and "after" to set up and clears up anything you did.

`before(:each)` and `after(:each)` are executed for every `it` block.